# mongorestore failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: EOF

Tags: restore, eof, mongorestore

I created mongodb dump with next command:

```
mongodump /host:%MONGODB_HOST% /authenticationDatabase:admin /username:username /password:password /oplog
```

After that I'm trying to restore dump with a command:

```
mongorestore /noIndexRestore /oplogReplay /numParallelCollections:1 dump
```

It restores all db and fails to replay oplog:

> Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: EOF

local mongoDB version: 3.0.2 (Windows 7)

remote mongoDB version: 2.6.7 (Windows 8)

Comment: I am also seeing this error. Dump and restore performed with MongoDB 3.0.2 on a Debian GNU/Linux 7. Doing a `bsondump` on the `oplog.bson` worked. I suspect this is a `mongorestore` bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the Go version of the [MongoDB tools](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools). I made a [pull request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/pull/19) on the GitHub project.

If you want an immediate solution, change the value of the `oplogMaxCommandSize` constant on line 17 of [mongorestore/oplog.go](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/r3.0.3/mongorestore/oplog.go) from `1024 * 1024 * 16.5` to `1024 * 1024 * 8`. Then recompile the `mongorestore` tool.

**Update**

Here is the [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-754). And here is the [official bug fix](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/commit/3f3078e129ac5bf01a087818109af00f4f677a35).

Comment: I am also getting same issue, may you help me how I can change this value and how to compile mongorestore tool.

Comment: @zafar this bug has been fixed for quite some time now. I suggest you use a more recent version of the mongo tools. It's easier than downloading and recompiling it. Anyway, if you want to compile manually, have a look at sections **Setup** and **Building Tools** of the [MongoDB Tools Project](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools) page.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your answer as only your post answer to this issue on net....Further I already installed latest mongo 3.2 and mongorestore utility worked fine...first I just downloaded mongorestore utility but it did not work...why I dont know even same we do for mysql or mysqldump utility then worked....Further I would like to go to depth of mongo so definitely explore link provided by you...thanks....